# Why win32com doesnt show me all emails

Tags: python, outlook, office-automation

I want to parse emails in python through the Outlook application. Running this code I get only a few of my emails.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
inbox= mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
messages= inbox.Items  
for i in messages:  
    message=i.subject  
    print(message)
```

I have tried changing the Default Folder and it happens everywhere.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason? Are you seeing the oldest messages? The newest? How many messages do you get?

Comment: It shows me some emails from a year ago but it should be much more...

Comment: Is that your actual code above? Or do you actually do something with the messages? What is the value of `messages.Count`?

Comment: This is the part of the code i am stuck. `messages.Count` shows only 20. The account is @windowslive.com, can this be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails were not visible beacuse they were on the server!

File-> Account Settings-> Account Settings...-> double click on your Exchange account-> set the Mail to keep offline slider to: All.

Found it [here !](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-access-old-emails-which-are-on-the-server/c2f97172-0191-4734-80e0-88d9488c3594)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that Outlook folders may contains different kind of items in the folder. So, you must be prepared for different items with different set of properties located in the same folder. For that reason I'd recommend checking the item type and only then try to get any property or call methods. Following that way you could process all items in the folder. Otherwise, when you call non-existing property or method an exception could be thrown in the loop and it will end its works suddenly.

You can use the `MessageClass` property of Outlook items for checking the item type. See [Item Types and Message Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/item-types-and-message-classes) for more information.

Comment: With messages.Count shouldn't i be able to see the number of all items?

Comment: The number of items in the folder of your store.

Comment: You can use MFCMAPI for observing internals of the store.

Answer (score 0):

*Try to get the `Count` , Example*

```
print(messages.Count)
```

*also to check item type, try*

```
if i.Class == 43:
        print(i.subject)
```

Comment: Already tried. It shows only 20 emails. The account is windowslive, can this be the problem?

Comment: Do you have multiple account?